# parseInt() returns NaN

Tags: javascript, html, string, integer

I have been working on a multiplication game [here](http://swaba.gaming.multiplay.co.uk/games/multiplication.html) for school in JavaScript.
My code returns random questions and determines whether the answer given is correct. It then, if correct, adds a point and shows up on screen. This is the problem - it just returns NaN. The points increment each time an answer is correct. I use `parseInt()` to add the number to a string and display it alongside the characters `Points:` but, instead of showing `Points: 1`, it shows `Points: NaN`.

```
<body>
    <p id="pts" style="text-align: right;">
    <script>
        generateNewQuestion();

        var pointsNo = 0;
        var pointsStr = "Points: 0";

        function generateNewQuestion() {
            var num1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
            var num2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
            var answer = num1+num2;

            var userAnswer = prompt("What is: " + num1 + " + " + num2 + "?");

            if (num1+num2==userAnswer) {
                // increments the points by 1
                pointsNo++;
                pointsStr = "Points: " + parseInt(pointsNo);
                // shows points on user's screen
                document.getElementById("pts").innerHTML = pointsStr;
                // ask if the user wishes to do another question
                var anotherQuestion = alert("Correct! You earn one point! Do another?");
                // give another if requested
                if (anotherQuestion == true) {
                    generateNewQuestion();
                } else {
                    alert("You're just not good enough..\n I get it... Your points are on the top right!")
                }
            } else {
                alert("Sorry, that was the wrong answer.\nThe correct answer was " + answer + ". Try another!");
                generateNewQuestion();
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but in your if statement, you can check if `answer == userAnswer` instead of adding again

Comment: @NuclearGhost I see. I was in the middle of adding that when I realised the points weren't adding so I stopped. Thanks for reminding me! ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically the issue is that you define the `pointsNo` variable after you execute your function. It's not known yet -> undefined -> `parseInt` will return `NaN`.

Place it before the function:

```
var pointsNo = 0;

generateNewQuestion();

var pointsStr = "Points: 0";

function generateNewQuestion() { ...
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3xfhrhtr/)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'll try it tomorrow. I have GMT±0 so I'm quite tired...

Answer (score 3):

You try to parse a number to integer for use as a string. Just skip it.

```
pointsStr = "Points: " + pointsNo;
```

and you need to move

```
generateNewQuestion();
```

after the initialization of

```
var pointsNo = 0;
var pointsStr = "Points: 0";
```

The declaration is hoisted, the variables gets declared, but has no value, until the value is directly assigned. A variable with value `undefined` and with `++` operator gets `NaN`.